# Concatenate numbers in a vector to form one number

Tags: c++, vector

I have a function which feeds a vector series of numbers. This series of numbers is to be appended to form a long long number and get stored in another vector.

Eg.

```
Vector1= |2|3|4|5|5|
vector2= |23455|     |
```

A space indicates the end of one number and functions starts to output second number series. I think reverse iterator and multiply by `10^x` is somehow a solution.

Eg code

```
vector<long long> a, fin;
for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)
{
    a.push_back(i + 1);    //  adds 1 2 3 4 5 6  in slots of v1


}
int j = 0;
for (vector<long long>::reverse_iterator i = a.rbegin(); i != a.rend(); i++)  { 
// want to append v1 members to form one number 123456 and store it in first slot of vector2;

    fin[0] += (a[(*i)] * (10 ^ j)); 
    j++;
}
cout << fin[0];
```

Comment: Help with what? How to call [`std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)? Help with reading the numbers from the standard input stream? Help with separating the numbers? Help with something else? And what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: I know how to push back man. I want to append which is not happening. Try it once. I tried to transfer from and to string. I used maths! iterate reverse the vector1, and then multiply vector[*iterator] by power of 10 and adding

Comment: if the long long number goes beyond long long then create your own class for handling such large number or use std::string. Else your method is correct for appending that is take first number, mutliply by 10, add second and again multiply and so on.

Comment: And appending is just what `push_back` does in a vector. It adds an element at the end. Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem and show us?

Comment: I think what he means is that he is trying to concatenate numbers in their decimal representation to form a larger number. e.g. He wants to take 5 single digit numbers like 2, 3, 4, 5 and 5, and concatenate them together to form the five digit number 23455.

Comment: ^yes absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't put any elements in your `fin` *vector*. Also you mistook `^` for *power* function. You need to use [std::pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow):

**Try:**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<long long> a;
    vector<long long> fin(1); // add an element

    for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)
    {
        a.push_back(i + 1);
    }

    int j = 0;
    for (vector<long long>::reverse_iterator i = a.rbegin(); i != a.rend(); i++) {
//      fin[0] += (a[(*i)] * (10 ^ j)); // ??
        fin[0] += ((*i) * pow(10, j)); // not ^
        j++;
    }
    cout << fin[0];
}
```

**Output:**

```
123456
```

Comment: can you help out with sstream class?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is probably to use a stringstream to convert the numbers to a string, then convert the string back to a number.

```
std::vector<long long> input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::ostringstream oss;
for (auto i : input)
    oss << i;
long long output = std::stoll(oss.str());
```

A more efficient way to do this, assuming you only have single digit numbers, would be as follows:

```
long long output = 0;
for (auto i : input)
    output = output * 10 + i;
```